# How to create a function that can print a nested list

Tags: python

I need to create a function that can print a nested list in a triangular format.

Example.

```
>>>thisList = hi(5)
00000
1111
222
33
4
```

I was attempting it through multiplying the int with 0, then multiplying with 1 then subtract 1.
Although, I think I am going about it the wrong way.

Edit:  Code

```
def thisList(num): 
   print ('0'*num) 
   print ('1'*num - 1)
```

Comment: We aren't going to do your homework for you, you need to show us what you have tried.

Comment: add your `hi()` function ...you forgot to add spaces before printing number string..

Comment: Use a loop. Choose a loop variable useful for calculating the length of the output string. Have another variable that stores the digit to be output. Modify this variable each time you go through the loop.

Comment: @IanAuld I have tried, Stackoverflow wouldn't allow me to publish it because it "wasn't in correct format". Anyways, I was attempting it through multiplication, then subtracting.

ex. def thisList(num):
     print ('0'*num)
     print ('1'*num - 1)

Comment: @AEL this happend with me when I tried to post my first question on SO. Actually Stackoverflow uses [mark-down](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Add you code in Question cover your code under curse and press crl+k

Comment: @AEL What you need to learn is for-loops in Python... read lanAuld's answer below

Comment: There's no list involved with what you're trying to do.  Nested or otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def hi(num):
    for i in range(num):  # iterates through the numbers up to num-1
        print(str(i) * (num-i))  # prints i as a string num - i times
```

outputs

```
>>> hi(5)
00000
1111
222
33
4
```

You should really read up on for loops and other control flows - https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop